# Create function to read only from file by [] operator c++

Tags: c++98

I was asked to create new class that adds certain features to fstream in c++.
Two of the features are [] operator that write to file and and second one is read only from file.
My header file of the class lock like that :

```
class RandomAccessFile{
     private:
        const ofstream writheFile; //Object for Writing:
        const ifstream readFile;   //Object for reading:
     public:
        RandomAccessFile(string fileName):writheFile(fileName), readFile(fileName){};
        inline const char& operator[](int num) const ; // read only from file by random access
       // some other functionality....
};
```

I try to implement the read only operator this way:

```
  const char& RandomAccessFile::operator[](int num) const {
    return readFile.get();
}
```

but I got the error:

```
no matching member function for call to 'get'
```

Wen I try the same this without the const in declaration it's works fine
what should I do to corrects this problem?
thanks.